# Difficulty Running Selenium Script with Multiple Manually Opened Chrome Profiles

Tags: python, undetected-chromedriver

I am working on a Selenium script to automate certain tasks in Chrome, and I've encountered an issue when trying to run the script alongside multiple manually opened Chrome profiles.

```
# Set Chrome options for headless browsing
chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Aryan\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 7')
chrome_options.binary_location='C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')  # Use a unique port number


# Launch Chrome browser in headless mode
# browser = uc.Chrome(driver_executable_path='C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options,use_subprocess=True)
browser = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options,use_subprocess=True,version_main=116)

# Navigate to YouTube Studio
print(colored('Navigating to YT Studio....','green'))
browser.get('https://studio.youtube.com/')
```

**Here's the problem I'm facing:**

I have manually opened Chrome profiles (Profile 1 and Profile 2) for my regular usage.

I want my Selenium script to open and use a specific Chrome profile (Profile 7) without interfering with the already open profiles.Yes, by terminating already opened chrome profiles solve the problem I don't want this.

When I run my script, it successfully opens Profile 10 but then gets stuck.

**Here's what I've tried:**

I'm using undetected_chromedriver to run ChromeDriver instances in separate threads for each profile.
I've specified different debugging ports for each ChromeDriver instance using the --remote-debugging-port option.
However, despite these efforts, my script still gets stuck.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to run my Selenium script with a specific Chrome profile alongside other manually opened profiles without any conflicts? Is there a potential workaround or additional configuration that I'm missing?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.